# Java + Oracle. Millones de registros

Tags: java, oracle

Buenos días, 
tengo una aplicación web (Java, jsp...) contra Oracle. Me gustaría saber cuál es la mejor manera para listar una tabla con 1 millón de registros y además poder exportar esta información a un fichero con extensión .txt 
Las pruebas hasta ahora dan errores de memoria: Heap space, Garbage Collector... No ha dado resultado positivo ampliar la memoria del servidor. 
Cuál sería el mejor método para el tratamiento de esta cantidad tan grande de información ¿? 
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Estaría bien que copiaras aquí tu código para ver cómo lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Básicamente, uso un PreparedStatement, al que le paso en un String la query. Le realizo un executeQuery() , recorro el resulset devuelto y voy añadiendo mis objetos a un ArrayList. El arrayList lo meto en la request y lo recorro en la jsp.
PreparedStatement stm = conexión.preparedStatement("StringQuery");
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
objeto = new Objeto();
)

Comment: ¿Y por qué no vas escribiendo la información al txt directamente en vez de meter todos esos registros en memoria? Para el listado lo mejor sería hacer lazy loading.

Comment: Pero necesito saber/recuperar que registros son para crear el txt con ellos, no?

Comment: Los recuperas pero no los guardas en el ArrayList, sino que vas escribiendo.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, pero digamos que en el DAO recupero la información y de alguna manera (ArrayList) se lo tengo que pasar al Action que es donde se genera el fichero txt ¿?

Comment: Genera el fichero en el DAO y pasa la ruta del fichero al Action

Comment: ok, entonces tendría el problema que; para generar el fichero uso el objeto HttpServletReponse, haciéndole un .setHeader y un setContentType. Y el objeto response no lo tengo en el DAO. Debería generar el fichero de otra manera ¿?

Comment: Tú hasta ahora estabas devolviendo un ArrayList hasta la capa de presentación, donde tienes acceso al HttpServletResponse. Ahora lo que tienes que hacer es retornar el path y en esa misma capa de presentación cargar el fichero a través de él, y asociarlo a la respuesta.

Comment: 1 millon de registros son invisibles para quien lo consulta... no deberia llegarle directamente el archivo? porque mover semejante cantidad de informacion tantas veces si puede hacerlo la DB? y en este caso pareceria lo logico...

Comment: Por lo que dice, también lista el resultado de la consulta.